# Storing data that includes functions

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

What I have is a list types of data, each identified by a name. For example 'length' and 'weight'. These are used to read and write bytes from files. Each metric stores a different amount of bytes, so I have a class Metric that stores for example a description and a byte length for the metric. Then, I can just keep a JSON file or an XML file of metric definitions that can be added to whenever.

I now want to differentiate how these bytes are read and written by adding a to_bytes and from_bytes method to the class. I could store the function definition as a string in the JSON file and just eval() it, or I could write separate child classes for each metric.

**What is the best way to store function definitions alongside other data?** I'm open to any suggestions, but the best solution is one that keeps it easy to manually add new metrics to the collection.

Comment: Writing separate child classes for each metric is **much better** than storing definition as a string in json file and using `eval`.

Comment: I don't see why you need to store functions here at all. It's generally a bad idea to mix logic with data. Just bite the bullet and implement those classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can pickle a function like everything else:

```
import pickle

def foo(x):
    return x*x

with open('myfile', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(foo, f)

with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
    moo = pickle.load(f)
```

print(moo(3))

output:

```
9
```

also works for the whole class:

```
import pickle

class MyClass:
    def foo(x):
        return x*x

with open('myfile', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(MyClass, f)

with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
    LoadedClass = pickle.load(f)

print(LoadedClass.foo(3))
```

output:

```
9
```

Comment: note that `pickle` just stores identifiers, not byte code or closure values.  therefore you can only pickle some functions, e.g. `pickle.dump(lambda x: x**2, f)` will fail